# Changing TableAdapter String

Tags: c#, datagridview, tableadapter

I am using tableadpters and datasets generated by wizards to connect a DataGridView to a source. 
I changed databases for the application, but I am getting an error for the stored procedures that still have the "OldDb.dbo.sp_GetWorkbarTypes" on them. I did a search for the "OldDb" and changed everything to "NewDb" but I till get a connection error saying that it cannot find "OldDb.dbo.sp_GetWorkbarTypes".
How do I change the adapters to point to the new Database?

```
this.sp_GetWorkbarTypesTableAdapter.Fill(this.workBarTypesDataSet.sp_GetWorkbarTypes);
```

throws a

```
Invalid object name Invalid object name
```

where the heck is this getting this string from? I changed them in the find

Comment: It's probably set to old db in the dataset designer. You could also try regenerating dataset from the db.